# Timers in Selective-Repeat protocol (C)

Tags: c, timer, udp

I am asked to implement a selective repeat protocol with UDP packets in C. I cannot use threads. I was told to use the `select` function. At the moment, my program looks like this. Both the sender and the receiver program will execute this loop in order to respectively send data and acknowledgement to the other :

```
fd_set sfds;
FD_ZERO(&sfds);

while(true)
{
    FD_SET(socket_file_descriptor,&sfds);

    select(socket_file_descriptor + 1,&sfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if(FD_ISSET(socket_file_descriptor, &sfds)) 
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

**Question** : How can I implement the sender's loop in order to have a timer for each packet that it will send? I've heard that `select` has a `timeout` argument but I'm not sure how it would help manage multiple timers.

Comment: Not clear, you should elaborate a bit more. BTW timeout can help you to design a "master" that manage received request, if any, and, on timeout, perform different actions, e.g.: poll slave devices.

Comment: Take note that `FD_ZERO(&sfds);` must be called each loop.